# Java EE 6 JDBC Connection stickyness

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I have a simple DAO that accesses JDBC connections via a DataSource.

When I call both operation1() and operation2() within a parent business EJB it actually uses two connections from the pool which seems to cause a performance issue at high volumes of calls since the pool is only so big.

1) The Connection I use must be container managed. So unwrapping the EntityManager's connection is not an option.

2) Under the hood EclipseLink is being used.

How do I get a single connection without polluting my parent business EJB with JDBC handling ?

```
@Stateless
public class MyDAO {
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/bla")
    private DataSource ds;

    public void operation1() {
        try (
            Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
            CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(xxx);) {

        }
        ...
    }
    public void operation2() {
        try (
            Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
            CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(yyy);) {

        }
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
@Resource(name = "jdbc/bla")
private DataSource ds;
```

to:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
private EntityManager em;
```

Then define a JTA datasource in your persistence.xml which maps to "myPU". That JTA datasource should map to JDBC resource that points to a JDBC connection pool. Both the JDBC resource and JDBC connection pool will be configured in your EE6 application server.

With that setup you will have connection pooling to your datasource and when you call `operation1()` and `operation2()` from a parent EJBs method they will be part of the same connection/transaction.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I get the underlying JDBC connection without a nasty entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class); I then have to manually handle the transaction.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you detail why you need the raw connection? That would add some helpful (to me at least) context to this.  Also, if you are using a JTA datasource, when you unwrap it, it will be in the same TX context as JPA - that's the same behavior when using and injected JTA datasource resource as well. I personally have not tested this but from what I have read I believe when you use this unwrapped JTA connection, or injected JTA datasource in a CMT EJB in EE6 you will still get CMT and not need to manually begin/commit your TX.

Comment: I am using Java EE 6 and need to call complex Oracle stored procedures. I think you are right. I double checked the EclipseLink doc. Seems you only need to manage the transaction if it's not JTA which makes sense. Let me confirm. Thanks http://bit.ly/1zgogOA